# Clicking the buttons on the Web page with C

Tags: c

My task is to open a web browser and click on the buttons that are available on the web page so that the clicked button performs its inbuilt operation defined in the web page. 
Was able to open a web browser using the C program.

But I was not able to complete the next operation using C.

Are there any inbuilt libraries where I can use them to click on the buttons in C?

A small provided example with explanation is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: can you please share the code that you have written until now as a self contained working example?

Comment: This question is extremely vague.  You don't state how the program is supposed to know what button to push.  Does it have knowledge of the layout of the web page, or does it have to infer it by some analysis of the rendered image?

Comment: Using the stdlib.h and the system(); function was able to open the web browser. I was not sure how I can script to click the buttons on the webpage. Do you think I can use the x-path of the button anyways? I didnt get proper idea to script that part. Help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You want to send mouse clicks or other input that normally comes from the user to an application. This is not part of the C language. It is dependent on the operating system and/or the window manager. You would need to specify what operating system you are using before more specific information could be given. Additionally, sending input to other applications may be subject to permissions controls, as applications should generally not be allowed to interfere with other applications.

Answer (score -1):

To provide this functionality you need to write your own browser (or at least its engine). Forget the idea:)

But you can  write the simple html parser to discover to buttons and simulate browser response to click. There are some html parsers written in C, for example: https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser You will also need the Javascript interpreter as often buttons are dynamically generated and serviced example : http://duktape.org/